# Rolling mean lag function for multiple variables

Tags: performance, statistics, r

Thanks to @josliber's help ([Rolling mean lag function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188388/rolling-mean-lag-function#188388)), I was able to speed up a rolling mean function for different groups and rollmean lengths.

Now I'd like to add to this function the ability to loop through different variables and bind everything together.

**Minimum reproducible example**

```
library(zoo)
dat <- data.frame(fips = rep(c(1001, 1003), each = 100),
                  x = rnorm(200),
                  x2 = rnorm(200),
                  x3 = rnorm(200))


allFipsRM3 = function(dat, varName, len){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$fips), function(x) {
    all.rm <- as.data.frame(sapply(len, function(l) c(rollmean(x[,varName], l), rep(NA, l-1))))
    colnames(all.rm) <- paste0(varName, "_rm", len)
    cbind(data.frame(fips=x$fips[1]), all.rm, data.frame(year=seq_len(nrow(x))-1))
  }))
}

outdat3 <- allFipsRM3(dat, "x", c(1, 2))

       fips      x_rm1      x_rm2 year
1001.1 1001  1.3482892  1.3043620    0
1001.2 1001  1.2604348  0.2990267    1
1001.3 1001 -0.6623813 -0.4243813    2
1001.4 1001 -0.1863812  0.2806624    3
1001.5 1001  0.7477061 -0.5111745    4
1001.6 1001 -1.7700551 -0.8463731    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, but certainly open to suggestions.

```
library(RcppRoll)

# Loop through n = 10
for (i in 1:10){

  # Create custom col labels
  lab1 <- paste0("x_", i)
  lab2 <- paste0("x2_", i)
  lab3 <- paste0("x3_", i)

  # Loop through each fips and calculate rollingmean
  dat <- dat %>%
      group_by(fips) %>%
      mutate(!!lab1 := roll_mean(x, i, align = "left", fill = "NA"),
             !!lab2 := roll_mean(x2, i, align = "left", fill = "NA"),
             !!lab3 := roll_mean(x3, i, align = "left", fill = "NA")) %>% 
    ungroup()

  # Progress bar for loop
  print(i)
}


> names(dat)
 [1] "fips"  "x"     "x2"    "x3"    "x_1"   "x2_1"  "x3_1"  "x_2"   "x2_2"  "x3_2"  "x_3"   "x2_3" 
[13] "x3_3"  "x_4"   "x2_4"  "x3_4"  "x_5"   "x2_5"  "x3_5"  "x_6"   "x2_6"  "x3_6"  "x_7"   "x2_7" 
[25] "x3_7"  "x_8"   "x2_8"  "x3_8"  "x_9"   "x2_9"  "x3_9"  "x_10"  "x2_10" "x3_10"
```